# Use a variable outside the function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I Can use a variable outside the function where it was declared?

Wanna Edit for full code, for more help in my case..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bank_id = null;
    var purpose_id = null;
    $('#bank_id').on('change',function(e)
    {
        bank_id = e.target.value;
    });

    $('#purpose_id').on('change',function(e)
    {
        purpose_id = e.target.value;
    });

    var data = {
        "purpose_id" : purpose_id,
        "bank_id" : bank_id
    };

    $.post("financialLoans/getRates", data, function(result){
    });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" required="" id="bank_id" name="bank_id"><option selected="selected" value="">Select</option><option value="1">Foo.</option><option value="2">bar</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" required="" id="purpose_id" name="purpose_id"><option selected="selected" value="">Select</option><option value="1">Foo.</option><option value="2">bar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you're using it outside the function, but its being executed immediately.  If you want it to execute after there is a change, then you should put the conditional block inside the function.

Comment: They way you have it the if gets executed immediately.  Either you have to have the change call the function or have a watch that kicks off when the variable is changed

Comment: i need outside of function for comparation with another dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `var` outside of all functions(same as global scope) to declare a global variable.
*Note: `var` will scope variable where it resides, outside of the function is the global scope (or the `window` object, same as the second example)*

```
var myGlobalVariable;
$('#bank_id').on('change',function(e) { ... });
```

Or, you can use [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) property:

```
$('#bank_id').on('change', function(e) {
    window.myGlobalVariable = ...
});
```

---

Snippet example:

```js
//global variable
var globalVar = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
    //NOTE: bank_id is inside $(document).ready() scope, not global. But you still can use bank_id whenever you want inside this one.
    var bank_id = null;
    
    $('#bank_id').on('change',function(e) {
      //using bank_id inside $(document).ready() scope! :)
      bank_id = parseInt(e.target.value);
      globalVar = e.target.value;
    });
    
    $('#another_input').on('change', function(e) {
      //checking bank_id in another function! :D
      if(bank_id == 1){
        alert("Second input: " + e.target.value + " and bank_id is 1!");
      }else{
        alert("bank_id isn't 1. :(");
      }
      alert("Global variable changed too, it was null, and now have the same value as bank_id.\nCalling by name: " + globalVar + ".\nAnd calling by window object: " + window.globalVar + ".");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="bank_id"/>
<input type="text" id="another_input"/>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was going say as well. If you need it 'everywhere' you are referring to global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the variable from the event handler inside some function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bank_id = null;
    $('#bank_id').on('change',function(e)
    {
        bank_id = e.target.value;
        changeSomething(bank_id);
    });

    function changeSomething(bank_id) {
       if(bank_id === "1"){
          console.log(bank_id);
       }
    }

});
```